# service stuck at pending start

Tags: windows, service

The thing is, i have a third-party application, that, somehow, in its service form, works properly only with the 'standard' name, the one with which it installs itself. Would i create my custom own service with the same parameters and binpath, but different servicename, the application just doesn't report (i'm not even sure what exactly it doesn't report even after examining msdn) to the OS that it started.

So the process is fine, it works and puts all kind of stuff in it's log, but for the OS the service stuck in 'starting...' state. And i need it to be able to work as custom named service as i need to run multiple instances of it (by the way in app 'desktop' form, multiple instances work fine so its not an architecture problem).

Please, any ideas of what can be done? 
P.S. I'm not a developer, more of engineer, so the idea of trying to disassemble .exe and finding what's wrong is a bit frustrating, but if someone could give detailed advice on doing so i would try, of course.

Thanks!

Comment: I actually ended up wrapping desktop mode of application with external service wrapper, which could be renamed as i like.

Answer (score 1):

The service is responsible for updating its status (see [Service State Transitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee126211(v=vs.85).aspx)).

It could be a bug in the software that is preventing it from updating the service state (e.g. hard coded service name used in Service-related [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058(v=vs.85).aspx)).